# WAPPSCmdlets is not installed on this machine

Tags: powershell, azure, windows-authentication, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

I have a Windows 2008 R2 machine, and I have installed the VS2010 and SP1, Windows Azure SDK 1.7 and all other tools of Azure SDK and PowerShell cmdlets from the below links

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/downloads/

When I run the Windows Powershell for Windows Azure Cmdlets, it is showing the error:

> Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'WAPPSCmdlets' is not installed o
>   n this machine.
>   At line:1 char:21
>   + cd c:\; add-pssnapin <<<<  WAPPSCmdlets
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (WAPPSCmdlets:String) [Add-PSSn
>      apin], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ad
>      dPSSnapinCommand

I have also tried the following link but no use.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/4c59fc7e-3ead-482e-88c3-f5555e915c84

Answer (score 1):

Could you try loading the module manually?

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1"
```

And then simply try any CmdLet (like `Add-AzureCertificate`) to see if you can use it.

**Update:** Since Add-AzureCertificate works for you this means all cmdlets are now available. To make things easier you can simply create a shortcut on your desktop with the following target:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit
>   -Command "cd 'C:\'; Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure*.psd1' | ForEach-Object
>   {Import-Module $_}"

Comment: Yes I have executed the above command, but after that simply command prompt came with no response. even after that if I open the Windows Powershell for Windows Azure Cmdlets, then the same error it showing. Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'WAPPSCmdlets' is not installed o n this machine.

Comment: yes Add-AzureCertificate is working, but the WAPPSCmdlets error is still there.

Comment: Since you can load cmdlets as modules or snapins, and you mentioned that Import-Module works, you can just continue using that. No need to install the cmdlets as SnapIn. So every time you need to work with these cmdlets, just import the module as @Sandrino suggested and work with the Cmdlets.

Comment: I wonder if you don't have an older version of the cmdlets previously installed, or if you have a profile that is attempting to load them.  The newer versions of the cmdlets do not even register a snapin at all, only a module.  Also, the new module is simply "azure" and not WAPPSCmdlets.  If you type "get-pssnapin -registered" and see the results do not include WAPPSCmdlets then indeed that snapin is NOT on the machine.  Also, type "notepad $profile" in PowerShell and look through the file it opens (if it is not blank) to see if there is a reference to WAPPSCmdlets.

Comment: Thank u, now without WAPPSCmdlets I am able to execute the Azure commands.